# ebXML\ebMS implementation in PHP

Tags: php, ebxml

Is there any example, testcase or definition in **PHP** to implement ebXML?

It is promoted as the b2b way to transfer data. But information, discussions and tools are nowhere to be found.

Am I looking on the wrong places or is using PHP to solve this an error?