# Electronic data interchange development over the years

Tags: web-services, rpc, edi, ebxml

I am writing a bachelor thesis on EDI and I would like to mention ebXML over there too, but it seems there's very small amount of information over the internet, is it still used these days?

Also part of the question I have to address is how technologies like (RPC, WebServices, ebXML and EDI) developed the data interchange.

Comment: For electronic data interchange, we are using `EDIFACT` and also `XML` in many flavors. `XML` mainly for webservices. I have to confess that I don't have current details on `ebXML`, but it has 260.000 Google hits, still.

Comment: ebXML seems to be rare indeed I had a similar question 2 years ago; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603951/ebxml-ebms-implementation-in-php

Comment: ebXML was supposed to be the standard that would kill traditional EDI.  It had some adoption, but retailers and wholesalers never adopted it.  That's why there's not a lot of examples.  So many tried to kill X12 and EDIFACT, and yet here we are, still talking about it.  Web services and API transport mechanisms have enhanced the interchange greatly in the past 10 years.

Answer (score -2):

You may be using the wrong search terms. Look for ebMS (ebXML messaging services), AS2 and AS4.